# Controller is there, but showing "Error code 404 page not found" in grails

Tags: grails

new.gsp:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
      <g:form name="myForm" controller="New" action="index" params="username:username">
      <div>
          <fieldset class="form">
               <label for="name">Name:</label>
               <div>
               <g:textField name="username" value="${params.userName}"/>
               </div>
          </fieldset>
      </div>
      <g:submitButton name="Submit" value="Submit" />
      </g:form>
</body>
<html>
```

NewController.groovy:

```
package sample
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.NEW;

class NewController {
    def index = {
        if($params.userName){
            render(view:"/login.gsp")
        }
    }
}
```

login.gsp is a simple page, having a simple welcome note.

if some body the solution please reply,

thanks in advance. 
by prasanth

Comment: have you got a `login` controller method?

Comment: render(view: "/login")

Comment: What url are you trying to access when you receive the 404?

Comment: @andymccullough no,, login.gsp is a simply page with some welcome notes

thank you for your response

Comment: @baxxabit i tried that also, still is not working..
thanks for your response ..

Comment: @codelark the url to the controller page

Comment: @codelark url to the controller index like http://localhost:8080/sample/new/index

thanks for your response..

Comment: what is $params? is it work without if() ?

Comment: @baxxabit yes, you are correct. '$' is not needed om params. but having the same problem,,

thanks for reply ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller name to "new" instead of New in 
    
It will work.

Or else you can modify your "save" action in controller, so that when you click on save button new page will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in the posted code that will cause you problems:

1. You're accessing the parameters with `$params` instead of `params`. The $ character is only necessary when you are in a `GString`. e.g. `def foo = "your username is ${params.userName}"`
2. Your view is named `new.gsp` but your action is named `index`. Grails will by default look for a view matching the action name in a directory named for the controller. In other words, since you don't tell it explicitly to render `/new.gsp` grails will look for `/new/index.gsp`. You can either rename the view to `/new/index.gsp` or tell grails to render the view `new` in the index action.
3. When attempting to render your logged in page, you're calling `render(view: 'login.gsp')`. The gsp extension is not necessary when calling the render tag. You're intended to use the grails view name, not the filename. `render(view: 'login')`
4. If you're using a recent version of grails (>2.0) you should be using controller methods rather than closures. e.g. `def actionName() { }` as apposed to `def actionName() = { }`. The reasoning is in the grails documentation.

Here's what it could look like with all the issues addressed:

rename `new.gsp` to `/new/index.gsp`. rename `login.gsp` to `/new/loggedIn.gsp`.

controller:

```
class NewController {
    def index() {
        if (params.userName) {
            forward action: 'loggedIn'
            return // render and forward don't end flow control
        }
    }

    def loggedIn() {} // no logic, automatically renders '/new/loggedIn.gsp'
}
```

Comment: i corrected, like what you said. Still its having the same error 
page not found 404.

thanks for your effort and response ,,

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to your controller named login.

```
def login = {}
```

Comment: my controller is new and the action to be called is index.

thank you for your response..

Answer (score 0):

If the view file is `new.gsp` then you need your action to also be `new` or else have a URL mapping (in `UrlMappings.groovy`) to do something like:

```
"/new" {
    controller = 'new'
    action = 'new'
}
```

*Or* you can set

```
static defaultAction = 'new'
```

...in your `NewController`.

Then Grails will find the appropriate action on your controller.

Comment: i tried, but still having the same problem,,

thanks for your reply ,,

Answer (score 0):

if your action is called index, you can acces the page on

```
localhost:8080/webapp/NewController
```